# get current Gruntfile within grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Is there a portable way to get at the currently loaded Gruntfile?

```js
grunt.registerTask('someTask', 'someTask in a separate grunt instance', function() {
    var gruntFile = getCurrentGruntFile(); // ???
    var done = this.async();
    var child = grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: "grunt",
        args: ['someTask', '--gruntfile=' + gruntFile, '-v'],
    }, done);
});
```

I needed to run jshint in a subshell because it was outputting color codes into the reporter-outputFile.  I imagine that there should really only be one Gruntfile per project, but setting a Gruntfile dynamically could be useful when developing grunt plugins or during initial configuration.

[Grunt.config](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config) only lists task-level options. The documentation for [Inside Tasks](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks)  doesn't list anything useful. [Grunt.util](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util) doesn't list anything relevant either.

---

**EDIT**

I have already set-up the jshint task using grunt.util.async to spawn a separate grunt in a subshell and pass it the `--no-colors` CLI arg.  I was simultaneously developing several different Gruntfiles for this particular project and I couldn't figure out a way to determine the currently loaded Gruntfile.  Fortunately, it was just a curiosity and this jshint task works fine if you have only one Gruntfile or don't need to change it.  Also, if it was a project requirement to have several Gruntfiles I imagine they could be kept in different directories and then the grunt tasks could be initiated in the relevant directory.

```
grunt.registerTask('jshintNoColor', 'jshint without color-code output', function() {
    var done = this.async();
    var child = grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: "grunt",
        args: ['jshint', '--no-color'],
        opts: {
            stdio: 'inherit'
        }
    }, done);
});
```

Comment: you can let jshint lint the gruntfile as a task within the gruntfile. to dynamically launch grunt, you can use a shellscript (exec) or nodejs (http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to spawn the grunt. Or you can have your grunt "builder grunt script" in a different directory as the one you want to execute later on

Comment: @japrescott i added the jshint code I used for the task. However, I only meant it as an example, I was really more curious if there is a straight-forward way to determine which Gruntfile is currently loaded